# Spring security with multiple userDetailServices

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

In my application, I have two types of users and they need to be authenticated from two different userDetailServices because their data exists in different tables. I am thinking to create different endpoints for these users. How can i invoke different userDetailService specific to different endpoints?

Comment: Can you share your code snippet? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If both the tables are within the same database, a simple way to address the requirement is to retain a single userDetailService and service it through union (or union all) of the two tables in the query (or equivalent JPA style).